# MVC Controller Subfolders with Views Subfolders

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

How do I move from one page to another if I have subfolders?

Controllers:

[image: Controllers]

Views:

[image: Views]

Actions:

**AccountController**

```
...
        [HttpGet]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Login...
        {

            return View("~/Views/Account/Login.chtml");
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Login...
            {
                ...
            return View("~/Views/Account/Login.chtml", login);
        }
       ...
       public IActionResult TypeRegister()
        {
            return View("~/Views/Account/TypeRegister.chtml");
        }
    }
}
```

From:
**Index Page [HomeController]**

```
<li><a asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Login">Log In</a></li>
```

To:
***Login Page [Accounts/AccountController]***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing the right thing but you have a typo. The file extensions are .cshtml not .chtml

`Views/[ControllerName]/[ViewName].cshtml
Views/Shared/[ViewName].cshtml`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/overview?view=aspnetcore-2.2